# Manejar un webView ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: javascript, android, html, api

Hola tengo un problema con mi aplicación al presionar el botón de compartir de  whatsapp genera el error net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME ya aplique el código en mi aplicacion que es el siguiente:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
            return false;
        }

        // Otherwise allow the OS to handle things like tel, mailto, etc.
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity( intent );
        return true;
    }
});
```

Funciona bien pero quiero saber si: ¿hay alguna manera por html o javascript que también se pueda solucionar ese error ?

Comment: Hola Richard de donde obtuviste esta validación para evitar ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME ?

Comment: Hola Jorge en un foro de esta misa pagina pero en ingles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697429/getting-neterr-unknown-url-scheme-while-calling-telephone-number-from-html-pag pero quiero q sea por html o por java si existe la posibilidad

Answer (score 3):

Se supone que lo que deseas cargar en el `WebView` es una url, en este caso el mensaje de error indica que lo que tratas de cargar no es valido, el esquema no es el de una url, tal vez estas tratando de abrir otros schemes o incluso custom schemes:

```
mark:
todolist:
abc:
mailito: 
telefonito:
myshcheme:
richard:
```

como ejemplo si usamos el esquema `telefonito:`, dentro de tu página que cargas en el `WebView`,

```
<a href="telefonito:123-555-5555">Call me now!</a>
```

al dar clic, este esquema no esta relacionado a una acción, obtendrás el mensaje de error:

> The webpage at ............. could not be loaded because
>   net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

en cambio si usas el esquema `http:` que representa una url, al dar clic funcionará sin problema.

```
 <a href="http://es.stackoverflow.com">Abrir stackoverflow!</a>
```

---

Los esquemas soportados por default son `http:`, `https:` , `tel:` , `mailto:` e incluso `market://` en un dispositivo android para cargar en un `WebView`.

Lo que realiza el código dentro de `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` es solo permitir cargar contenido dentro del `WebView` las url que inicien con `http:` y `https:`, cualquier otro esquema lo manejara mediante un `Intent`, en este caso te recomiendo validar también que solo pueda realizar el intent para `tel:` y  `mailto:`, ya que en otros caso también puede provocar un error (por ejemplo `telefonito:`) :

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
                    return false;
                }

               //Agregar validación para email y telefono. 
               if( url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("mailto:") ) {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                  startActivity(intent);
               }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Pero no existe manera por html o script ?

Comment: Si se validara por javascript no habría forma de realizar un intent, podrías realizarlo realizando una JavascriptInterface pero es realizar un trabajo innecesario.